# Configuring appindicators

Tags: gnome, indicator, gnome-shell, gnome-panel, gnome-shell-extension

Assuming that the gnome extension "Ubuntu Appindicators" is the one that's putting the indicators in the top right corner, is there any way to configure it?  Other, similar extensions allow configuring the icons (e.g. size, changing to greyscale).

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: I didn't, sadly.